# Since a copy was made, No corruption on Source drive or Target drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, hashing

.
Definition:
A hash function is an algorithm that
compresses messages of arbitrary length into
short digests of fixed length.

Would doing 3 hashes (md5, sha1, sha512)
give more certainty
than doing 1 hash (md5)?

How to get near absolute verification that the files are the same?

Said differently:

Would 3 successful hashes (md5, sha1, sha512) 
achieve more certainty that the
Source files and
Target files are the same?

(Suggesting:
No corruption on either drive since a copy was made)
One concern is:
The media might decay since files copied.

After a copy and a hash (md5) are done Ok then 
computer is restarted and 
a compare (Hash) is done after restart.

Why 3 different hashes?
Do 3 different hashes to conclude that it is 
more certain that there are 
no corrupt files after a copy was made.

Details:

Computer 1
D:\Temp is 200 GB = 200,123,456,000 bytes,
about 104,000 files
Windows copy
D:\Temp to S:\Temp (S = Storage hard disk drive)

MD5 hash passes Ok
D:\Temp = S:\Temp (all good)

Move (S = Storage hard disk drive) to computer 2 to do Long procedures.

Computer 2
copy (S = Storage hard disk drive, S:\Temp) to U:\temp
U drive is usb 2.0 drive 256 GB memory stick.

200 GB hash Testing results from
Hard Disk Drive to USB 2.0 memory stick:

151 minutes to DirHash_md5
150 minutes to DirHash_sha1
152 minutes to DirHash_sha512

It takes about the same time to do each hash,
about 151 minutes.

151 minutes to do 1 hash or
453 minutes to do 3 hashes (md5, sha1, sha512).

DirHash.exe = 336 KB (344,624 bytes)
https://www.idrix.fr/Root/content/category/7/31/46/
by Mounir IDRASSI copyright 2010-2018

Batch files example with sample output:

"C:\dirhash.exe" "S:\temp" sha1 -progress -nowait -quiet u:\DirHash_sha1_S_Temp.txt

B0C4CFECD3DC13B22EA3D6E26AE4FB167D5F38D7
B0C4CFECD3DC13B22EA3D6E26AE4FB167D5F38D7

"C:\dirhash.exe" "U:\temp" sha1 -progress -nowait -quiet u:\DirHash_sha1_U_Temp.txt

windows File Compare:
FC.exe /b
"u:\DirHash_sha1_S_Temp.txt"
"u:\DirHash_sha1_U_Temp.txt"

FC: no differences encountered

Said differently:
Would 3 successful hashes (md5, sha1, sha512)
achieve more certainty that the
Source files and
Target files are the same?

(Suggesting:  No corruption on either drive since a copy was made)

--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would doing three hashes (`md5`, `sha1`, `sha512`) give more certainty than doing one hash (`md5`)?

Unlikely, unless you suspect the files may be subject to tampering with by a third-party. For simple "these files are the same" calculations, any hash algorithm (including `md5`) should be fine.

> How to get near absolute verification that the files are the same?

Use a strong hash algorithm (e.g. `sha1` or preferably `sha512`), which is [collision resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science)).

> Would three successful hashes (`md5`, `sha1`, `sha512`) achieve more certainty that the Source files and Target files are the same?

No, not generally, at least as far as I am aware.

> One concern is the media might decay since the files were copied.

`md5` should be sufficient to detect this phenomenon in most cases.

> It takes about the same time to do each hash, about 151 - 152 minutes.

Then, as a suggestion, you should use the (single) hash that you feel is best suited to your situation.

> Windows File Compare: no differences encountered

Then everything is likely the same.